# How to create an HTML Table out of HTML Form submissions without server side programming?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2010

I would like to know if this is possible in Javascript? I need to create an HTML Table that will be updated everytime a user submits a form. I do not have php or sql access because I was only provided with Sharepoint access. It 's actually a sub site of the enterprise sharepoint page but I have admin rights to this sub site so I was able to create a home for our region.

What I need to create is an employee evaluation/coaching form but I do not want to use sharepoint forms/surveys because the design is limited. I need to be able to track every form submission that can be pasted to an excel file. I hope this is something that can be done. Thanks!!!!

Comment: No. Javascript (without server side programming) can only affect what a single user sees, as it runs in the user's browser. How about Google Forms (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=en)?

Comment: You can manipulate form information with javascript but it would be just local and reset after a refresh.

Comment: Also check out the [Parse SDK](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart/) for storing data in the cloud

Comment: All list (form) submissions are "tracked" by virtue of it being a list item, added to a list. the list can be exprted as SharePoint, without any need for custom JavaScript.

Comment: ^ Exported as Excel - Sorry, typo.

Comment: @PaulLeigh what I was thinking is an automated database being updated everytime a user submits a form then I'll export it to excel every week. Is it possible to maybe get the list data save it somewhere in sharepoint or maybe create my own database system that uploads somewhere I have access in?